# PHP composer xdebug warning

Tags: php, composer-php, xdebug

New to PHP. Working on a PHP project and have xdebug enabled to be able to debug my php applications. The production server does not have xdebug enabled because it is handled by another team. On my local machine, when I run composer it gives me a warning saying

```
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on 
runtime performance.
```

I do not want to disable xdebug when I am developing. Just wanted to confirm that running xdebug in dev environment should have **no impact** on the composer installing libraries/performance of the app on the production server.

Comment: Do you run `composer install` (for instaling production-dependencies on production server) in a ssh-shell directly on the production server, or on your local machine? The latter will be slower if XDebug is enabled, but you might need XDebug for e.g. PHPUnit...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> I do not want to disable xdebug when I am developing. Just wanted to confirm that running xdebug in dev environment should have **no impact** on the composer installing libraries/performance of the app on the production server.

There is a huge impact of just loading Xdebug. It slows the Composer run down by 3x or 4x, even when the profiling feature is not enabled.

In other words: xdebug is invaluable for debugging, but increases the memory used and processing time of Composer.

---

**How to disable Xdebug for Composer runs?**

My suggestion is to write a little invocation helper for running Composer.

The helper is a bash or batch script calling PHP with a custom `php.ini`, especially configured for Composer. Lets call it: `php.ini-composer`.

You could copy your current `php.ini` and adjust it for the Composer run, by removing xdebug or commenting it out, like so: `;zend_extension = "/path/to/my/xdebug.so"`.

While you are at it: setting `memory_limit=-1` is helpful, too.

The full command looks like so on Windows: `php.exe -c php.ini-composer composer.phar %*`

Just clone the idea for a bash script.

---

And you may find the full answer to your question in the Composer FAQ.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#xdebug-impact-on-composer

It was added/updated just a few hours ago.

---

Some alternatives (instead of using seperate ini file) are also mentioned [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/7a06615bf06c5a391ab2d360907012529508e695#commitcomment-14591475).

Comment: Just to reconfirm - it has no impact on the actual running of the app right on a production server where xdebug is not installed? I do not mind composer being slow.

Comment: Confirmed. No impact, if not loaded! (Additionally: you can always speed your production system up a bit by reducing the number of loaded extension to the absolute minimum needed by your application.)

Answer (score 7):

Modern versions of Composer can work around having XDebug enabled by default for the CLI SAPI. It spawns a new PHP process with the XDebug extension disabled in case it is detected.

You can disable this behaviour by setting the following environment variable:

```
COMPOSER_ALLOW_XDEBUG=1
```

Found this in the documentation: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#xdebug-impact-on-composer

Comment: @ojrask Just one question, where should I use this variable to make it work?

Answer (score 5):

Like with web scripts, expect CLI scripts to run slower as well.

If you need the added runtime performance, you can disable XDebug on CLI only. Set your PHP installation so that it uses different ini files for CLI and your server, [as this answer suggests.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894042/how-to-disable-xdebug-loading-for-php-cli?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

To fix this, prior to PHP 7 people would suggest to comment out the extension from your php.ini file.
However, in **PHP 7** they are no longer in there.

Instead, we use the `phpdismod` command.

```
sudo phpdismod -s cli xdebug
```

The -s flag tells it to disable Xdebug for the CLI SAPI (/etc/php/7.0/cli) and not FPM.

And just like that, the warning message should be gone. No need to restart PHP.

In addition to this, there is a [plugin](https://github.com/hirak/prestissimo) that downloads packages in parallel to speed up the installation process.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `phpdismod` works only for PHP 7.0, so if you need to disable xdebug for any other version, comment all lines related to `[xDebug]` block in:

`/etc/php/php_version_here/cli/php.ini`

And restart php (replace 7.4 with PHP version for which to disable xdebug in CLI):
`sudo service php7.4-fpm restart`

Comment: Thanks, this command won't disable xdebug when we debug, but still remove the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file named `php-composer.ini` somewhere with the following content (the minimum php config for composer):

```
extension_dir = "D:/php/ext/" ;according to your system
extension=php_openssl.dll
memory_limit=-1 ;optional
```

Now create a file named `cmz.bat` with the following contents. (edit paths accordingly)

```
@ECHO OFF
php -c "D:\php-composer.ini" "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar" %*
```

add this file to your system path or your project root.
Now use `cmz` instead of `composer` and you will not see that message and hopefully the composer speed would be increased.

note: Some package need specific php extensions. you need to add them to `php-compsoer.ini` file or appending `--ignore-platform-reqs` switch to `cmz.bat` file

Answer (score 1):

On a fresh download of Symfony 3.1 and PHP 7.0, you can run the following (having edited it to include the path to your composer.phar file):

```
php -n -d extension=json.so -d extension=phar.so -d extension=pdo.so -d extension=ctype.so /path/to/composer update
```

If you have any extra vendors to your `composer.json` file, you might find that they have a dependency on an extension, so you need to include that by adding `-d extension=name_of_extension.so` to the list.

What's happening here is the `-n` flag goes with PHP defaults - it doesn't load any `ini` PHP config files, so XDebug is never loaded. Then each of the `-d` flags allows you to dynamically set config values, so you can include extensions.

Comment: Thanks, I spent too long trying to define multiple extensions like `-d extension=phar.so;extension=pdo.so;` or `-d extension=phar.so,pdo.so;`