# Composer installer warning

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

How can i resolve this warning when installing composer?

```
Some settings on your machine may cause stability issues with Composer.
If you encounter issues, try to change the following:

The xdebug extension is loaded, this can slow down Composer a little.
Disabling it when using Composer is recommended.
```

Comment: why get rid of it? better keep it.. its the smart xDebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of this message, by disabling the PHP extension xdebug in your `php.ini` for your Composer runs.

Referencing:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33928053/1163786
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#xdebug-impact-on-composer